# $P[ e^{tX} > e^{ta} ] =?$

Tags: probability, exponentiation, expectation

Can anyone help me understand why given any random variable $X$, the following stands true?

$$
 \forall t > 0, P( e^{tX} > e^{t\epsilon}  ) \le e^{-t\epsilon} E[e^{tX}].
$$

I found it in the proof of [`Hoeffding's Inequality`](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=stat705/Lecture2.pdf) (Lemma 5).

Comment: Check out Markov's inequality: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are given that $t > 0$. The event $\{e^{tX} > e^{t\epsilon}\}$ occurs exactly when $X > \epsilon$, and so
$$\begin{align}
P\{e^{tX} > e^{t\epsilon}\} &= P\{X > \epsilon\}\\
&= \int_\epsilon^\infty f_X(x)\,\mathrm dx\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathbf 1_{x\colon x > \epsilon}\, f_X(x)\,\mathrm dx\\
&\leq \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{t(x-\epsilon)} f_X(x)\,\mathrm dx\\
&= e^{-t\epsilon} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx} f_X(x)\,\mathrm dx\\
&=  e^{-t\epsilon} E[e^{tX}].
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $P\left(e^{tX}\gt e^{t\xi}\right)$ is a decreasing function of $\xi$,
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}\left[e^{tX}\right]
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty P\left(e^{tX}\gt e^{t\xi}\right)\,\mathrm{d}e^{t\xi}\\
&\ge\int_{-\infty}^\epsilon P\left(e^{tX}\gt e^{t\xi}\right)\,\mathrm{d}e^{t\xi}\\
&\ge\int_{-\infty}^\epsilon P\left(e^{tX}\gt e^{t\epsilon}\right)\,\mathrm{d}e^{t\xi}\\[6pt]
&= e^{t\epsilon}P\left(e^{tX}\gt e^{t\epsilon}\right)
\end{align}
$$